# Use HyperLink in JqGrid Column and call a controller method by passing the cell value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid in my MVC4 where i want to enable a `**hyperlink**` for each row in the column,
On click of this hyper link i want to send the cell value as a parameter to the controller method.
i want this call to be an ajax call.

I have tried multiple ways of doing this by going through the answers of **Oleg**
i.e. using `dynamicLink` ,`loadcomplete` and `showlink`
The below code is the last attempt that i made which was not successful.

```
   colModel: [{name: 'ResponseId', index: 'ResponseId', width: 150, formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: 'javascript:',
showAction: "GetAndShowUserData($('#tblJQGridCCVT')'",''#divtblJQGridCCVT'', addParam: "');"


<script>
var MyBase = {};
MyBase.GetAndShowUserData = function (grid,tagetDivSelector,param) {debugger};
</script>
```

Can someone tell me where i am drifting away?

**Note:** i would prefer `showlink` over other options

Comment: Could you specify which version of jqGrid you use () and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? You should additionally describe more clear (on an example) which exactly hyperlink you need to have in the column (href value, custom onclick ...). It's important to know which rowid you use and which columns with **unique** values you have in the grid. Are the values from `ResponseId` column unique? Is it the native id of you data?

Comment: @Oleg i am using jqgrid version 4.6.0